# update average/count from another table

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I've been provided the below schema for this problem and I'm trying to do two things:

1. Update the ACCOUNT table's average_eval row with the average of the evaluation row from the POST_EVAL table per account_id.
2. Update the ACCOUNT table with a count of the number of posts per account_id, with default value 0 if the account_id has no post_id associated to it.

Here's the kicker : I MUST use the `UPDATE` statement and I'm not allowed to use triggers for these specific problems.[image: provided schema]

I've tried `WITH` clauses and `GROUP BY` but haven't gotten anywhere. Using postresql's pgadmin for reference.

Any help setting up these queries?

Comment: Its a very bad idea keeping counts in an Owner Row. They will invariably be wrong as people will forget to maintain them properly. If you can write a query to calculate it, then use that query when you need to see that number

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'm using Postgres. I included MySQL to broaden the answer pool. Should I have not? This is only my 3rd post I believe, so I'm not quite used to posting questions all that well.

Comment: No, please do not tag databases that are not relevant. It will just lead to answers that might not work with the database you are really using. Btw: you are probably getting more/better answers if you provide a little SQL script that defines the tables together with some sample data, so whoever is trying to help doesn't need to come up with their own and type everathing. [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12) is a good site to share things like that

Comment: The help we can give is "what have you tried so far ?"  And what problems did you meet finding the solution to your problem?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for the suggestion. I'm definitely keeping this (and [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12)) in mind for the next question I post on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first question can be done using something like this:

```
update account a
  set average_eval = t.avg_eval
from (
  select account_id, avg(evaluation) as avg_eval
  from post_eval 
  group by account_id
) t
where t.account_id = a.account_id
```

The second question needs a co-related sub-query as there is no way to express an outer join in an UPDATE statement like the above:

```
update account a
  set num_posts = (select count(*)
                   from post p
                   where p.account_id = a.account_id);
```

The `count()` will return zero (`0`) if there are no posts for that account. If a join was used (as in the first statement), the rows would not be updated at all, as the "join" condition wouldn't match.

I have not tested either of those statements, so they can contain typos (or even logical errors).

---

Unrelated, but: I understand that this is some kind of assignment, so you have no choice. But as RiggsFolly has mentioned: in general you should avoid storing information in a relational database that can be derived from existing data. Both values can easily be calculated in a view and then will always be up-to-date.

Comment: This worked wonders. Haven't gotten to views as of yet, but I assume those don't store anything on the database, which is why we might use them to calculate age from date of birth for example? In this case we would only need to store the DOB and create a view to calculate age?